# Reducing bandwidth usage of vlc audio playback from smb share

Tags: vlc, libvlc

I'm looking for a way to reduce a java based media player network bandwidth usage. During my research I found out that quality can be traded for lower datarates on streams with the `transcode` options. In my case the audio source is in a samba network share (file based - only wav type), and I'm not sure if the `transcode` setting apply for it.

The source of my problem is that our customer's work site has only a 50Mbit connection to their datacenter, and many clients (~10) has to be able to play back these audio files simultaneously. There is no QoS i guess, and the network is used for other purposes too. Caching is not an option (it's a long story, that i can't tell).

I would be really grateful if someone can clarify it for me. Can I lower the bandwidth requirements in this scenario by lowering the quality with `transcode`?

I'm open for other suggestions too, if you have an idea.

Comment: Is there a reason the client can't simply convert copies of the files beforehand, providing the option to use the original or the smaller copy, based on location?

Comment: Yes these playbacks are time sensitive. The backend appending wav files continouosly, and clients has to be able to playback as those gets written (like a stream). It's not good, but I can't change this infrastructure.

Comment: Without knowing the full story, it sounds like your client replaced a car with a truck and still expects it to fit in the garage. The solution, increase bandwidth or transcode the video from the source. Logically, transcoding from the users end, with a samba share, 
 means you are still reading the whole .wav file, which should mean it slows it down even more, as all you achieve is adding an extra process.

Comment: Yes, your explanation is correct, that is why I'm really out of ideas. I hoped transcode can manage some magical on-the-fly processing, but this is clearly not the case. Anyway, thank you for your time.